# array in array won't bind .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, binding

I'm currently working on a webpage in asp.net MVC5 with a complex datamodel that should be bound. code structure of the models:

```
public struct RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems
{
    public RiskAssessmentItemType Type;
    public CheckBoxVM[] ItemCheckBoxVMs;
}
public class ItemsForRiskAssessmentViewModel
{
    public int RiskAssessmentId { get; set; }
    public RiskAssessment RiskAssessment { set; get; }
    public RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems[] RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems  { set; get; }
}
public class CheckBoxVM
{
    public bool     Checkbox{ get; set; }
    public Int64    Id      { get; set; }
    public string   Label   { get; set; }

}
```

The `RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems` seems to be bound correctly but the items in the object are null. I can't get it working after multiple tries.
The fields that should be bound in the objects are sent with the request, see the post-section of the request, taken from chrome:

> RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems[0].Type.Id:15
>   RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems[0].ItemCheckBoxVMs[0].Checkbox:true
>   RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems[0].ItemCheckBoxVMs[0].Checkbox:false

My HTML page code :

```
<h2>@Model.RiskAssessment.Description</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  @for (int index = 0; index < Model.RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems.Length; index++)
  {
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems[index].Type.Id)

     RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems typesWithItems = Model.RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems[index];
     <h3> @typesWithItems.Type.Description </h3>
    <br/>

     for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < typesWithItems.ItemCheckBoxVMs.Length; itemIndex++)
     {  
         CheckBoxVM itemCheckBoxVM = typesWithItems.ItemCheckBoxVMs[itemIndex];
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems[index].ItemCheckBoxVMs[itemIndex].Checkbox, new { @id =itemCheckBoxVM.Id} )
         @itemCheckBoxVM.Label
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems[index].ItemCheckBoxVMs[itemIndex].Id)
         <br />
     }
  }
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value=@StringResources.Save class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult SetItemsForRiskAssessment(int riskAssessmentId)
{
    RiskAssessment riskAssessment=Database.RiskAssessments.GetRiskAssessment(riskAssessmentId);
    var vm = new ItemsForRiskAssessmentViewModel {RiskAssessment = riskAssessment};
    var riskItems =Database.RiskAssessmentItems;
    List<RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems> tmpList= new List<RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems>();
    foreach (RiskAssessmentItemType iType in Database.RiskAssessmentItemTypes.GetRiskAssessmentItemTypes())
    {
        var typeWithItems = new RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems
        {
            Type = iType, ItemCheckBoxVMs = riskItems.GetRiskAssessmentItems().Where(i => i.RiskAssessmentItemTypeId == iType.Id).Select(raItem => new CheckBoxVM {Id = raItem.Id, Label = raItem.Name + " " + raItem.Description}).ToArray()
        };
        if(typeWithItems.ItemCheckBoxVMs!=null && typeWithItems.ItemCheckBoxVMs.Any())
            tmpList.Add(typeWithItems);
    }
    vm.RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems = tmpList.ToArray();
    return View(vm);
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SetItemsForRiskAssessment(ItemsForRiskAssessmentViewModel vm)
{
    RiskAssessment riskAssessment = Database.RiskAssessments.GetRiskAssessment(vm.RiskAssessmentId);

    return SetItemsForRiskAssessment(riskAssessment.Id);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should always try shorting the code as much as possible, post only what you suspect the problem might be, reading such a long question is not really pleasure to many people.

Comment: Why is `RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems`a `struct`?

Comment: I really don't know a college wrote that part, and he's on a hollyday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. by changing this code:

```
   public struct RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems
    {
       public RiskAssessmentItemType Type;
       public CheckBoxVM[] ItemCheckBoxVMs;
    }
```

To :

```
public class RiskAssessmentTypesWithItems
    {
        public RiskAssessmentItemType Type { get; set; }
        public CheckBoxVM[] ItemCheckBoxVMs { get; set; }
    }
```